# Global navigation to homepage

Tags: sub-site, global-navigation, promoted-links

I've added a SharePoint subsite and have created promoted links to browse to reports. Now the global navigation refers to the promoted links, while rather i'd like to point to the home page of the subsite, where I will be able to add multiple libraries later.

I've tried:
Site settings -> navigation

But I'm not able to edit the link. Therefore the setting to refer to the homepage rather than the promoted links should be somewhere else. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to solve the issue via disabling the minimal download feature. It seemed to have triggered a cleanup of the cache as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Term store Management in this case. But for using this, you have to configure Managed Metadata Service.

Comment: Thnx Prasad. Unfortunately configuring Managed Metadata service is not an option.